# Invoke a fluter method from the iOS share extension without opening a app

Tags: ios, flutter

I was creating a Flutter project that requires an iOS share extension that communicates with the flutter service without opening the main application. I tried to use flutter 'receive-share-intent' which partially does the job but open the main application to perform the service. But I want to don't want to open the app but invoke a flutter service.

There are some solution that I wanted to try but it only works with the main application like creating a FlutterMethodChannel

```
let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
let {channel_name} = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "samples.flutter.dev/{channel_function}", binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
 {channel_name}.setMethodCallHandler({
      (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
      // This method is invoked on the UI thread.
      // Handle messages.
    })
```

But this doesn't work with the extension as expected. To create the method channel we need a flutter view controller but I don't know how to reference it for the custom share view controller.
If anyone has any idea about it, please help me with this.

Comment: A share extension runs in a separate process.

Comment: Is there any method to use the flutter service if we group the iOS extension with the main app?

Comment: There is some discussion [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/107482).

Comment: Ja, there is only discussion but not the proper ideas about this. Let's hope somebody will update it.

Comment: The other challenge is that extenisons have less memory available to them. You may want to consider writing the extension as native code

Comment: Ja , the extension is the native code but the for the services I wanted to use the common service for android/ios.

Comment: Then you need to work out if you can link a dart-based framework into a Swift app extension. As far as I know you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

It's now possible to run Flutter inside Share Extension

https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/ios/app-extensions